# Accepting SQL Query in JSP Form

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jsp

What I am using: PostgreSQL, Netbeans, Tomcat Server, And JSP and HTML

To avoid that the question is a duplicate ia mtrying to explain it cleary :):

I already get connect with the JDBC Driver to the database Uni with a few tables. So now what I am trying to do is if the user enters a Query in the form

```
 Please enter a Query: ...............
```

like

```
SELECT * FROM Student
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT Student.name
FROM Student NATURAL JOIN Transcript JOIN Professor USING (pid)
WHERE Professor.name = 'Artem';
```

or

```
SELECT semester, year, COUNT(DISTINCT cid) AS NumberOfCourses
FROM Transcript
GROUP BY ..., ...
```

If the user entered a Query it should print out the result.
So here  I stuck  and  not sure how to implement it with Java

If you want I can add my code  but that would be to much for this post. its only a simply accessing database from JSP

Comment: Do you know how to implement it in simple JAVA? If yes then you can implement it in the same way in JSP as well.

Comment: If you go through this page, you will learn . http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25320/querdata.htm#CIAIIABE

Comment: simply post the query at the server side and send back the result back to the client in simple HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String query = request.getParameter("query");
if(query!=null && !"".equals(query))
{
        Connection con = new DBConnection().getConnection();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int  totalColumn = rsmd.getColumnCount();


        out.println("<table border='1' style='border-collapse:collapse'>");
        out.println("<tr>");

        for(int i=1;i<=totalColumn;i++)
        {
            String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
            out.println("<th>"+columnName+"</th>");
        }
        out.println("</tr>");

        while(rs.next())
        {    
            out.println("<tr>");
            for(int col=1;col<=totalColumn;col++)
            {            
                Object obj= rs.getObject(col);                    
                out.println("<td>"+ String.valueOf(obj) +"</td>");
            } 
            out.println("</tr>");
        }
        out.println("</table>");
}
```